# Get the coords and height/width of a svg group into python

Tags: python, gtk, svg, rsvg

Hi I want to load the groups of a svg-file into several gtk pixbuffs/subpixbufs
therefore I need the coordinates and width and height of them

I'm currently just using rsvg and gtk 
is it possible to get those information with that modules ? Or do I need another module to read out that data from the svg-file?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out to simply use `RSVG::Handle::get_dimensions_sub(id)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist in rsvg here. >>> print "get_dimensions_sub" in dir(rsvg.Handle) # prints "False"